# Azure Devops, query based query

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, jira

has anybody found a capability of filtering / querying by a query in azure devops which exists in Jira, is very handy ?

In Jira it works as follows:

1. you create a query like - show me all the stories, or whatever - this will be filter=12345 after saving
2. you create a filter like "where filter=12345 and issue_type=bug and whatever criterion"

This is very useful when you want to build up complex queries like sum of some (filter=12345 and filter=12346), or find issues which are in the filterA but not in filterB (filter=13245 and filter!=12322) or just make your dashboards depending on a single query and in various gadgets you show just subset of items (of the main filter).

Is there any way to do something like that in azure devops ?

Everything, searched on internet, found the possibility of querying by "query text" field, but it works based on the test suite. As far as I see there is no option to do that.

Comment: No, Azure DevOps does not support that